# How to save arguments of function call in Rhino Mocks? 

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

```
    MockRepository mocks = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();  
    IActiveProgram  repository = mocks.CreateMock<IActiveProgram>();  


    var readPrg = new ReadProgram();
    readPrg.init("333", "eee", "", null, repository);
```

In `readPrg.init` I will have a several calls on `repository` object.
For example `repository.AddProgram(programName);`

How I will be able to know later on exit from `readPrg.init` to know the arguments that my prerecorded function calls been executed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd call `repository.AssertWasCalled(x => x.AddProgram(programName))` after you call init. Look also in [the original post of Rhino Mocks AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax)
Another option, you could use Expect:

```
repository.Expect(x => x.AddProgram(programName)).Repeat.Times(50)
var readPrg = new ReadProgram();
readPrg.init("333", "eee", "", null, repository);
repository.VerifyAllExpectations()
```

Comment: for example if my repository objects was called 50 times with adding a new records in the init function , so I should now run repository.AssertWasCalled 50 times with the added values.

Comment: Take a look at my edit - you can set the number of times you expect the method to be called